# Navigate in divs with table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to navigate in a table. Without the table it works, but with nope!
here's the code :

```
<table>
<th><div class="section selected"><a href="#">E1</a></div></th>
<th><div class="section"><a href="#">E2</a></div></th>
<th><div class="section"><a href="#">E3</a></div></th>
</table>
<br />
<a href="javascript:;" id="button">CLICK</a>
```

then

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$('.selected + .section, .section:eq(0)')
    .last().addClass('selected')
    .siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

CSS

```
.selected{background:red}
```

And How to triggered the link with Enter Key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might want you want to do:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var selected = $('.section.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    var tbl = selected.closest("table");
    var th = tbl.find("th");
    var index = selected.closest("th").index();
    if(index < th.length-1) index++;
    else index=0;

    tbl.find(".section:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('selected');
});
```

this is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MNkaF/2/).

**The problem** in your code was using jQuery `siblings` function, which goes through the all node siblings at the same DOM level, for instance if you had:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <div class="section selected"><a href="#">E1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="section"><a href="#">E1 Sibling</a>
        </div>
    </th>
</table>
```

then sibling function would select the `E1 Sibling` node, but non of `.section` nodes in your html are siblings.

Comment: It works from link 1 but goes directly to the last link... Don't get it!

Comment: @Kris88: I did it just as a sample and also because you has used `last()` in your code. after click which one do you want it to go to?

Comment: I would make kinda loop : 1,2,3 then again go to 1,2,3

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work...    if(e.keyCode == 37){
       $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected')
      .closest("table").find(".section").prev().addClass('selected');
     }
     if(e.keyCode == 39){      
       $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected')
      .closest("table").find(".section").last().addClass('selected'); 
     }
     if(e.keyCode == 13) {       
       document.location = $("div.section.selected a").attr('href');
     }

Comment: @Kris88: I changed it as you asked. check my answer again and new working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MNkaF/2/)